# List of packages filtered by last update period

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

Is there any way to get a list of packages (or some request/project related) filtered by last-release date period?

I've found [this ubuntu list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) but hasn't any filter by date/period option.

I've also search dpkg-query/apt-get syntax but don't find any key to filter by this criteria:

```
# hypothetical key --last-releaset=<months> 
# results: list packages with number of months since 
# the last stable release date >= <months>
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade --no-install --last-release=12
```

Additionally I've seen some related questions posted before, but not issues about these filters (by date/period).

Answer (score 0):

- AFAIK, Debian repository does not include the release date, package creation date or any other date in the default package listing. You may check it yourself, for example:

  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz

  So no way for APT to know.
- However, there is a possibility for a workaround using a custom script that build minimal package list with their file attributes including creation & last modification dates from an FTP repository, example:

  ftp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main